Is math a bad discipline for teaching jobs or is it just me?
I saw a post on reddit about how "getting a R2/not R1 job/teaching a 3:3 load" is not so bad as long as you enjoy teaching the courses you teach. I agree with that sentiment, it's intuitive.
There's the thing: I am a math postdoc.  I like teaching, but I can't help but think math is a pretty bad discipline if you are taking the above POV.
Certainly at the PUI where I did my undergrad, 80% or so of math courses are first year "service" courses for other majors.  That means basically teaching undergrads how to walk or ride a bike from a math point of view.  If you have the patience for that, I guess it works --- but I worry this would eventually get very boring otherwise.
I have an engineering undergrad background.  Now that I have a math PhD, I would say some of the engineering courses I took (required, second and third year courses) are almost closer to applied math grad courses --- the kind of classes I would want to teach --- than upper-level undergrad math electives.
And, in terms of job satisfaction, I get the sense that engineering (just to give an example) upper-level courses have the benefit of "you will need this in the future" in a way that the non-major service courses (even upper level math) don't.  Students want to learn (or at least feel they should learn) what you're teaching.
As for upper-level math undergrad courses, I get the sense that these are so often taught as "get up to graduate level or else you are done" courses (particularly at the most competitive places) that it takes away from the fun.  (At least one R1 professor I TA-ed for gave joyless honors courses, where it was clear that 80% of what mattered was being the best student.  Granted, at a R2 or PUI (Primarily Undergraduate Institution), you would have to do something different and it would make perfect sense to bring passion to the subject or try to breathe life into the seemingly dry or difficult subject matter, but I imagine it's hard when you can easily imagine your colleagues at other institutions tsk-tsk-ing your efforts.)  I feel like if I was teaching undergrads at not-Harvard, it would be hard to escape the fatalism of "90% of you should already seriously consider not taking this class too seriously and finding internships in industry."  (Also a problem at most R1 places, but at least you have the sense that teaching undergrads is only one part of your job.)
You can contrast that with (again) engineering where students have a puncher's chance at doing an interesting course project or senior project --- and (in the US) may be interested in staying for a master's (hence potentially more interesting research/project topics) --- whereas in the US serious math students are basically trying to go directly to the PhD and master's theses seem to be quite rare (notably, compared to Europe).
So, am I on to something here?  There was never a question I wanted to do a PhD in math, but it seems like a bad choice if you see yourself heading towards "non-R1" jobs because so much of the teaching is quite low level compared to what you are doing your PhD in, your research projects, etc. --- and it obviously hurts that there isn't a big (industrial) source of interest in the topics that you want to teach.
Anyone else see it this way?  I thought I would possibly consider non-R1 jobs because I really like math and ideas and have fun preparing lectures and problem sets and working with students, but now I wonder if I'm too interested in solving interesting, really challenging problems* and my own personal growth for non-R1 to be a great option.  (It could be I'm giving engineering courses too much credit as well.)
I have certainly seen this "I'm too enamored with my own research to have the patience to mentor/teach you" mentality from R1 professors before so it's not hard to recognize it in myself.
I also contrast this with the humanities, where teachers basically seem to be able to skip prerequisites (often) all together and jump straight into "sexy" courses that meld current events with classic literature, etc.  (Case in point: I knew PhD students in English who were pitching their own "seminar" courses on trendy topics while all I taught as a PhD student was basic calculus.)
*No offense to teachers, I just think good teaching is more about learning how people think and managing people than sitting down and thinking through a challenging problem, or discovering something no one has noticed yet specifically.  But I guess that's part of the question: what do you do to keep yourself interested/challenged in teaching-heavier jobs?

I find this interesting, but it's more of a discussion forum post that seems likely to attract opinions than a question that sits well in the StackExchange format. By the way, I'm at a R2 that's maybe going to get bumped to R1 because of the reclassification next year, and our load is 2:2. This is something like the limit of being able to do research and have a life, but I thought I'd point out that your internal model may be slightly off on the teaching load distribution.

A position at a STEM focused college (e.g. a “school of mines”) might interest you.  The math teaching is still mostly service teaching, but it is in calculus based engineering/applied math courses.

In looking at this post for a couple of minutes, I can't tell what the question is.  Can you minimize your presentation to ask a single semi-objectively answerable question?

The take away I get from your post is, man, you had a bunch of bad teachers.

The whole math curriculum (here the word "whole" is only slightly exaggerated) from kindergarten through math graduate school heavily emphasizes mastering technical skills that are valuable only if one later studies things that most of the students will never study. (E.g. math graduate student take courses on functional analysis without ever finding out that its main uses are in the study of differential and integral equations, and freshman calculus students never find out that values of derivatives are rates of change (really!) and 9th graders never find out what algebra is for, etc. And....

. . . . and very rarely does any mathematician notice that that way of teaching math is obviously the cause of the misunderstandings of mathematics that the broad public has: The public (including professors in other fields) is unaware that mathematics, like physics and biology, is a field in which a torrent of new discoveries is constantly being published, or that mathematics isn't just mechanically executing algorithms. Those misunderstandings will continue until mathematicians wake up.

@MichaelHardy That's a complete mischaracterization. It is of course true that many mathematicians teach unrelated to any applications of the material. It is of course also true that many mathematicians really try to teach their students useful skills that will help them find jobs and be successful.

@MichaelHardy: "freshman calculus students never find out that values of derivatives are rates of change" well, maybe they are assumed to know that already? (Admittedly many years ago) when I was in school this was 11th grade math. But then, (IIRC grades ≈ grades 7 to 9) we also did proofs. I recall them most prominently in geometry. And of course it's bad teaching to assume such knowledge to the extent of never stating it in the course.

What is PUI? I'd really wish that people stop assuming that everyone is familiar with their own unique acronyms.

Have you considered a non-research type school? The college I work for (ITS and adjunct for programming courses) has an agreement with the local university, so we get a constant inflow of people who need the pre-engineering/physics math (up thru calc w/ diff equations IIRC) and are completing it with us as a pre-admission program to the big U.  No publish or perish, you get smaller groups of students (25 or 28 max class size), 4 sections per major term (fall/spring, summer courses are extra pay beyond regular contract) plus the usual state school benefits, etc.

This question seems to be asking two quite different things. The title asks "Is ... bad ... or is it just me?" and halfway down the body of the question, "Anyone else see it this way?". If that is the question then it's an opinion poll and doesn't belong here. The question at the end, "what do you do to keep yourself interested/challenged in teaching-heavier jobs?", is on-topic, so the title and the rest of the question text should be edited to make this the focus.

As the help pages state, "To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where […] there is no actual problem to be solved: “I’m curious if other people feel like I do.” [...] your question is just a rant in disguise: “______ sucks, am I right?”"

@cbeleites It sounds as if your experience in school was very similar to mine. But it is not at all like that of the overwhelming majority of students taking first-year calculus.

@Dilworth: PUI = Primarily Undergraduate Institution. It's not the asker's own unique acronym, but a standard designation used by the NSF (= National Science Foundation, the main US government funding agency for science and math). But I agree it helps to expand it.

@NateEldredge. Thanks. But it is unique to those living in the US. Majority of scholars, and people in general are not living in the US and are mostly unfamiliar with the unique American terminology and acronyms.

Consider the case of elementary school teachers. There are many who are truly excellent at it, love their job, and have all of the necessary skills. It's worth pointing out that being able to read and write, and perhaps do elementary school mathematics, is a rather small part of the skills you have to have to be good at elementary school teaching. It is profession (in the sense that the people who are good at it are professionals who are good at what they do), not a bunch of washed out philosophy majors. To think otherwise is disrespectful to those who strive to get better at their job every day.
The same is true for those who chose to teach mathematics. Many of those who chose teaching are truly excellent at it. Their daily challenge is to find ways to convey information better, in view of changing demographics and changing technology. Their challenge is not to stay challenged by the material they teach. To think otherwise is disrespectful of the professionals who on average do a far better job teaching than those tenure-track folks at R1 institutions who, largely, teach in the same way as teaching has been done for 100 years or more and who know (or should know) that there are much better teaching methodologies they do not care to learn (or don't have the time to learn).

In many cases, tenure-track folks at R1 institutions are teaching the way they do because they don't have access to enough resources to teach any other way.  Your options are limited when you have 200 students and only one TA.

should know: Academia has the peculiar situation that people who have received a good and full professional training in some field are then "subjected" to two changes of profession* which are never even announced in this way (and many do not realize this): from the professional on field x to management of researchers and to teacher of field x. To me it is extremely weird that tertiary education institutions do not seem to realize this and do not offer the corresponding professional training ("research management for STEM people", "STEM didactics for university teachers", ...)


one may even go a step further and argue that already professional in x -> to researcher is at least partly such a change in profession as well, and also there the training in the sense of tertiary level education is somewhat limited. (In my field, analytical chemistry, industry profession and academic research may be more similar than in other, even STEM, fields - so I don't see that much of a difference.)


@cbeleites I agree about the management stuff, but nearly every university has a Center for Teaching Excellence (perhaps under a different names) that provides training to faculty about how to teach well. It's just that the incentive structure for faculty is so that most don't make learning how to become a better teacher a priority in their professional development.

@WolfgangBangerth: over here (Germany), many but not all Länder (states) nowadays have a (= one) center for university didactics. Bavaria requires (new) professors to take some courses - and the didactic center states that they try to serve the new profs for now, all others who teach at university are not allowed to take those courses because they don't have the capacity ... A friend in the UK was denied by his university administration to take such a course a few years ago...

Don't make the (frequent) mistake of assuming R2 universities are less rigorous or have lower standards than R1 places. The difference between them is scope, not quality. R2 universities have research in fewer disciplines, even 1 (medicine, say) than R1 places. Even primarily undergraduate colleges and universities can have very high standards for teaching, while having moderate requirements for research.
If you are at an R2 that actually focuses on math as a key area, then you will have high expectations for research. If math is considered only as a support field, then less.
Moreover, most places you have some influence over the decisions on which courses you teach (most of the time). And, even at R1 places you might get a Calculus I course with 800 students and 30-some TAs on occasion. And most "research" universities also have a strong commitment to the undergraduate program. Some (Duke, CMU, ...) have specialized teaching faculty (Professor of the Practice) for this, but not all do. When they do, the "research" faculty is free to focus on upper level and graduate courses.
In some ways math is the ideal field for someone who wants to teach, and isn't too bothered by teaching lower level courses. This is because most majors at most universities contain some math requirements, leading to a relatively high demand for faculty since nearly every student takes some math (US perspective, of course).
How to keep challenged, has the same answer for everyone. You keep engaged with colleagues and find a way to have frequent conversations about theories of common interest. At an R1 (or R2 focused on math) you have immediate colleagues to engage with; as close as the coffee lounge. At a primarily undergraduate institution you need to find those contacts. One way is to find some sub-field of common interest with your local colleagues. Another is, depending on geography, to visit other "local" universities with more faculty and a wider range of interests. For the truly isolated you may need to find travel money for such visits and/or conference attendance. Once you have a circle of contacts/collaborators, however, it becomes easier in the age of the internet, Zoom, etc.
But even at an R1, you need to spend effort to stay engaged. It won't just fall on you.
See Wikipedia: List of research universities in the United States

At R2s, you still have colleagues close by who have common interests: Namely, how to teach well.

Fairly obviously, for the reasons you mention, teaching undergrad math is probably less satisfying than teaching undergrad philosophy, for example. For one thing, philosophy is not usually used as a filter, that is, not as a required course which may be intellectually disconnected from one's eventual major, but a good grade is required in order to get_into one's desired major. Math is used as a filter, so we find probably a majority of people being required to take some calculus... not because they necessarily need it, but, supposedly, that it's an "objective" test of intellectual strength.
A somewhat misguided reason for imagining that "it's objective" is that the daily lives of most people do not include constant interaction with (substantial) mathematical ideas. In contrast, people do use language all day long, every day, even on weekends... and use language to argue about amateur-philosophical, social, political ideas very often. So most people are literate in their native language, and familiar with using it to express a huge range of ideas. Good. But absolutely not familiar with mathematics to do anything at all.
Not unreasonable... but the situation does amount to teaching some incomprehensible language, with a different alphabet, syntax, referring to unfamiliar phenomena... to kids who don't have any reason to care. Dang.
All the worse, in large state schools (R1 or not), the huge bulk of required-course calculus students makes it simplest to have a uniform required text, uniform exams, etc., so that individual instructors have no control over any of that. And the textbooks are very profitable for publishers, so there's constant (artifical) churn...
... and the bloat in those textbooks does really give a stupid idea of what calculus is, and how useful it is. It's essentially "anti-calculus". :)
Apparently, at smaller schools, where there is more emphasis on undergrad education, there is also much more leeway about the textbook and syllabus, so that there is room for discretion and more-genuine discussion of actual intellectual ideas... rather than just gate-keeping the students.
Some of the coercion is in the name of "uniformity", but uniformity is a sad goal. Sometimes better than certain alternatives, yes, but, ... sad.

So most people are literate in their native language, and familiar with using it to express a huge range of ideas. I would challenge this statement. It is true that most people can connect the words according to the grammar rules (by the way, chatGPT can do it even better than most), but often what they say is ambiguous at best and self-contradictory at worst. The speakers/writers with really good command of the language are as rare as people with good understanding of math. and to master the natural language is harder because it is imprecise by its very nature. Math is way easier.

@fedja, haha! Yes, I agree, for some of us, math is waaaaay easier than other things. In part, possibly, because it does not necessarily require extensive acquaintance with human society. :)  But, in my observation, many/most people are completely accustomed to the imprecision of standard language. The very idea that anything could be "precise" is completely alien. :)

"many/most people are completely accustomed to the imprecision of standard language" Whether I agree to this claim or not heavily depends on how you define "accustomed" :lol:. But, OK, if we want to talk more about that, we'd better move to chat...

(Full disclosure, I have never taught, and my uni days are a few decades past, but I did enjoy some mandatory maths courses, and even took higher-level maths later on as a side-kick during my CS studies. So consider myself being on the receiving end of what you are talking about.)
From a psychological POV, on the side of the teacher, your line of thinking seems very pain-inducing to me. You are writing a lot about problems that your students may or may not have, like it only being important to be in the top-20%, not actually knowing the content.
I would suggest that as a teacher, that is not what your focus should be. Back in my uni, I was one of those very few who actually deeply enjoyed all the mandatory and voluntary maths I heard, compared to 99% of my fellow students. I especially enjoyed when the teacher was good. That was in a time when fully half of the new CS students had to abort after 4 semesters because of not managing the minimum scores in pure maths courses (not CS related at all).
Now don't get me wrong, aside from about 1 or 2 black sheep, I have nothing to say against any of those profs back then. But there is a difference between hearing a course about group theory in the context of cryptanalysis from a weathered old guy who not only wrote a standard book about the topic, or two, and has plenty of fascinating stories to tell; and another prof who starts the first lecture by writing "0.0.0.0 Definition 1", followed by "0.0.0.1 Axiom 1" and so on an forth in an unbroken line to the end of the semester, with not a single word that you wouldn't read in a (dry) book anyways.
So I imagine if I had decided to go into teaching, my focus would have been to not worry so much about how the pupils/students are doing, but about how I can motivate the joy or at least fascination about these topics. I mean yes, for many studies, the first maths courses are like "learning to walk", and for many of them the students don't ever need any of those learnings again in their lives, neither at the uni nor later when working. But still, I assume being into maths yourself you do find all of that fascinating; and I assume very strongly that it is possible to find fascinating aspects even in the basics (or especially in the basics).
So TLDR: don't worry about how great your uni or your students are, but about how you can make your courses as great as possible. Make your courses so great that non-maths students wonder whether they picked the right discipline and whether they want to switch to full-time maths instead... :-)

I know some people who were TAing parallel problem sessions in a math for computer science class, who even started an informal competition, about how many people they could convert. As far as I remember the year after that had a surprising number of people who switched their degree to mathematics. And it definitely makes classes more useful then the standard "here is what you need to know for the exam".

@mlk, surprising number of people who switched their degree to mathematics wow, nice to see that what I meant as a joke really happened somewhere. Probably more the exception than the rule, but still.

Consider this quote about bonsai, lightly edited:

... the word ["bonsai"] is [commonly] used to describe virtually all miniature container trees, whether they are authentically trained bonsai or just small rooted cuttings.
Technically, though, the term should be reserved for plants that are:

grown in shallow containers
following the precise tenets of bonsai pruning and training
resulting in an artful miniature replica of a full-grown tree in nature.


What do you do to keep yourself interested/challenged in teaching-heavier jobs? I'm challenging myself to consider an undergraduate course as bonsai research. Many researchers already do so, but casually. Dig up dead old theories, loosely graft on the state of the art, and hack corners off until it fits into a semester.
I don't want to denigrate this approach -- this is already an above-median teaching approach, compared to simply reciting and regurgitating a textbook.
But I am more curious, year after year, whether I can shape a course into an authentic learning journey, which is interesting and memorable on its own terms. One around which the time constraints are not just incidental or restrictive, but fundamental. (Then again, "real" research must be completed in finite time as well.)

If I began with one concept, how could I present it most simply and clearly?
How would I most naturally develop it?
What one pivotal misconception must I pre-empt?
If my audience only ever remembers one thing, what would it be?

By the way, these are fantastic guardrails for writing scientific papers and grant applications too. Communication is universal. Improving your communication skills will improve your research career, and teaching is a phenomenal test-bed for communicating.
But good teaching can also genuinely uncover new knowledge (not "just" better presentation), since it's usually bonsai pure research rather than applied research -- especially for earlier years. Just this morning, while testing a simple demonstration of ionic strength, I discovered that dissolving enough salt in grocery store double strength vinegar high-molarity ethanoic acid is exothermic -- dissolving that same salt in water hardly gives off any heat. This both demonstrates the ionic strength effect (in the same demo, the vinegar's pH decreases measurably) and connects it directly to energy release.
Or, put succinctly: there sits a point, between every student misunderstanding and its correction, where a theory plausible to the student is defeated by reality. The only difference between teaching and research is that in teaching I am, just occasionally, not the primary student.

I really like this observation, but unfortunately, it's not about math (and the crux of the OP is that math may be categorically different from other disciplines in this way).

OP just says 'I contrast this with the humanities, where teachers [can] skip prerequisites ... and jump straight into "sexy" courses' -- since OP came from engineering, I am really not sure they think engineering is fundamentally different from math in requiring prerequisites. If anything, I think "bonsai research" is more likely to flower into real research in math all the time -- two physicists just stumbled onto a new series for pi with one free parameter, in 2024! https://phys.org/news/2024-06-physicists.html

or an undergrad helping to disprove the local-global conjecture in Apollonian circle packings https://www.quantamagazine.org/two-students-unravel-a-widely-believed-math-conjecture-20230810/ or a teenager showing how frequently Carmichael numbers appear https://www.quantamagazine.org/teenager-solves-stubborn-riddle-about-prime-number-look-alikes-20221013/
By contrast, I highly doubt there is simple undiscovered chemistry that isn't being commercialized somewhere.

Mathematics is not about equations, formulas and such.
Mathematics is about logic and problem solving using "doctrine" of applying proven principles on, for you, undiscovered ground.
Mechanical and electrical engineering have huge advantage over math that you can touch the problem or visualize it more clearly than math concepts. It's much easier to get "gut feeling" about the solutions in mechanical engineering and electrical engineering.
On the other hand, without mathematics the engineers would waste hell lots of time fine-tuning their designs manually.
If you want to motivate your students don't tell them "Without [advanced calculus] you're done", tell them "Without [advanced calculus] you're done, because you won't be able to this [easily / cheap / fast]..." Curiosity is great motivator.
Use extensively (expected) real-life examples, especially interesting or funny, and apply methods you are about to teach.
My calculus teacher started derivatives chapter by question: "Do you know why could be imprisonned for taking pictures of important vehicles(*) in motion [in Czechoslovak Socialistic Republic]?" Then he showed us sequence of three images of a tank riding from a ditch. From the reference points in the picture (track width, fence height) and camera frame rate he derived rough estimates of the tank's power, in-field performance etc.
Then he started with definitions of derivative...
(*) Important vehicles were army equipment, trains, heavy trucks, airplanes.

There is, at a minimum, some marked differences of opinion about whether this is good practice in a math class or not, e.g.: http://www.madmath.com/2022/08/proofs-and-applications.html

That does not go in conflict. Motivate by real-life exampes and teach the concepts behind.
